# How to correct Div overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I am writing code for my first site and I am facing a problem. I added a DIV `#footer` to the code and it is overlapping an existing DIV completely.

The code is below, can you tell me what I am doing wrong, and how I can fix it?

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>ABOUT</li>
            <li>WORK</li>
            <li>TEAM</li>
            <li>CONTACT</li>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="second_section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="copy">
            <h1>ACTUATE CONTENT</h1>
            <h3>Expert content for every business</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="third_section"></div>
<div class="fourth_section">
    <div class="col">
        <img src=
        "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/55-files-and-documents/512/Icon_17-512.png">
        <h2>Research</h2>
        <p>We use the most advanced research methods availble to focus down
        into your subject matter.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <img src=
        "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/55-files-and-documents/512/Icon_17-512.png">
        <h2>Writing</h2>
        <p>Our writers are seasoned and have honed their craft using the best
        of the best</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <img src=
        "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/55-files-and-documents/512/Icon_17-512.png">
        <h2>Editing</h2>
        <p>We also do editing for up and coming writers in the literary
        genre.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    display: block;
}

.header {
    background-color: #333;
}

.nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav ul {
}

.nav ul li {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 20px;
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: 20px;
}

.second_section .container {
    background-image: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-I0jOcWYqW94/UdFZ9U8Si0I/AAAAAAAACRw/2Hhb0xY7yzY/s1600/84.jpg);
    height: 900px;
}

.copy {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 100px 50px 500px 500px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Garamond;
}

.third_section {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.fourth_section .col {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-right: 6%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Garamond;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.fourth_section img {
    height: 32px;
}

.col {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Garamond;
}

#footer {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css, you've used `display: inline-block;` and `float: left;` together. That is not necessary. They kind of have similar effect. Removing `float: left` solves the problem...

```
.fourth_section .col {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-right: 6%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Garamond;
    width: 20%;
    /* float: left; */
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftnfhkfL/)

but causes another one. Your `.col` elements don't have the same height. They go like `260px, 242px, 242px`. Columns with the shorter height are aligned at the bottom. You can fix this by adding `vertical-align: top` to `.fourth_section .col`.

```
.fourth_section .col {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-right: 6%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Garamond;
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftnfhkfL/1/)

Comment: It's `float: left;` on the elements with `.col` that cause the parent to ignore the height of those elements, _not_ `display: inline-block;`. Floated elements are taken out of the normal flow of the document.

Comment: @hungerstar I've just noticed that he also used float. Updated my answer.

Comment: Removing the float _"sort of"_ solves the problem. The content of `.fourth_section` are not top aligned anymore.

Comment: Fixed that one also.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an empty div between your footer and the other div setting clear property, this will avoid the overlapping. This happens because you are using `float: left` on `.col`;

css:

```
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

Js Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fvknvqqL/

More details

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Comment: Clearing DIVs are bad practice, one should use a `clearfix` and apply to the appropriate elements as need. Here is a great [clearfix solution](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `float: left;`. check this

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div {
  display: block;
}
.header {
  background-color: #333333;
}
.nav {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.nav ul {} .nav ul li {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 20px;
  font-family: serif;
  font-weight: 20px;
}
.second_section .container {
  background-image: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-I0jOcWYqW94/UdFZ9U8Si0I/AAAAAAAACRw/2Hhb0xY7yzY/s1600/84.jpg);
  height: 900px;
}
.copy {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 100px 50px 500px 500px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Garamond;
}
.third_section {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}
.fourth_section:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.fourth_section .col {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
  padding-left: 6%;
  padding-right: 6%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Garamond;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
.fourth_section img {
  height: 32px;
}
.col {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Garamond;
}
#footer {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #333333;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">

    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>ABOUT</li>
        <li>WORK</li>
        <li>TEAM</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="second_section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="copy">
        <h1>ACTUATE CONTENT</h1>
        <h3>Expert content for every business</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="third_section">
  </div>

  <div class="fourth_section">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/55-files-and-documents/512/Icon_17-512.png">
      <h2>Research</h2>
      <p>We use the most advanced research methods availble to focus down into your subject matter.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/55-files-and-documents/512/Icon_17-512.png">
      <h2>Writing</h2>
      <p>Our writers are seasoned and have honed their craft using the best of the best</p>

    </div>



    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/55-files-and-documents/512/Icon_17-512.png">
      <h2>Editing</h2>
      <p>We also do editing for up and coming writers in the literary genre.</p>
    </div>


  </div>

  <div id="footer">
  </div>











</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> just add css to your code for 'fourth section' as below:

```
.fourth_section{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

> that's it!

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the issue has to due with the use of floats. Elements that are floated are taken out of the normal document flow and do not take up space, though other elements will respond to them (i.e. text flowing around a floated image).

Use a clearfix like the [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) on elements containing floated children or add `clear: left;` to `#footer`.

```css
#footer {
    clear: left; 
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noted that you did not close the ul tag, that's why the code is misbehaving. Close the tag and all will be well

```
<div class="header">
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>ABOUT</li>
        <li>WORK</li>
        <li>TEAM</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Incase you ever face a problem with div overlapping, just add

```
clear:both
```

to the css and all will be well.